# Using an anonymous user id in asp.net core 3.1, like Request.AnonymousID from .Net 4.x?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there a built-in way to handle a cookie-based Anonymous UserId between sessions in asp.net core, or do I need to roll my own / some third part thing? Just like [Request.AnonymousID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.anonymousid?view=netframework-4.8) did in 4.x days.

**Background**

I have done a bunch of searching for "Asp.net core anonymous user id" and related things, and this seems like one of those things, that I feel like there must be a great solution for - but I am just not searching for the right keywords...

I did find something in github/nuget called [AnonymousID](https://github.com/aleripe/AnonymousId/tree/master/AnonymousId), but is is quite old and has a lot of strange dependencies, that makes me weary to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up taking https://github.com/aleripe/AnonymousId/tree/master/AnonymousId and just adapting it to 3.1 - and it works perfectly.

Answer (score -5):

> You can also use the AllowAnonymous attribute to allow access by non-authenticated users to individual actions. For example:
>
> ```cs
> [Authorize]
> public class AccountController : Controller
> {
>     [AllowAnonymous]
>     public ActionResult Login()
>     {
>     }
>
>     public ActionResult Logout()
>     {
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This would allow only authenticated users to the AccountController, except for the Login action, which is accessible by everyone, regardless of their authenticated or unauthenticated / anonymous status.

Reference: [Simple authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple)

Comment: Sorry, but that was not what my question was about at all. :)