# How would I implement the AnonymousId\Anonymous User functionality found in (classic 4.x) ASP.NET in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-middleware, anonymousidentification

I want to implement or use the AnonymousId\Anonymous user functionality found in the older ASP.NET MVC 4 system but in a ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application.

I have seen 3 NuGet packages which seem to do it but 2 are very old, and the third has very little documentation. In another very similar question, user KJensen ([Using an anonymous user id in ASP.NET Core 3.1, like Request.AnonymousID from .NET 4.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61141663/1375926)) mentioned using a NuGet package ([NuGet AnonymousID](https://github.com/aleripe/AnonymousId/tree/master/AnonymousId) but said he updated it for 3.1.

Unfortunately, he didn't elaborate, and I don't have the reputation points to make a comment or ask him (or not that I could figure out how to). I use stackoverflow every day, but I don't post much obviously.

I haven't tried much; I did include the NuGet package that KJensen mentioned but as he mentioned in his answer to his own question it did have a lot of dependencies. I guess I'd like to know how he updated it etc. I hope this is the correct mechanism to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not need to be updated for version. You can find the corresponding [Class Library](https://github.com/aleripe/AnonymousId/tree/master/AnonymousId) in its [GitHub repository](https://github.com/aleripe/AnonymousId) and use it directly.

For example, I create a class library named `AnonymousId` and copy the file from GitHub to my class library:

[image]

Of course, you need to install the corresponding NuGet package to ensure that it will not report an error(`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions`, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features` and `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens`):
[image]

Then create your project under the same solution(ASP.NET Core 6 MVC):
[image]

Reference class library:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\AnonymousId\AnonymousId.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Add middleware in Program.cs:

```
app.UseAnonymousId();
```

In Controller:

```
public string Test()
{
    string anonymousId = "";
    IAnonymousIdFeature feature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IAnonymousIdFeature>();
    if (feature != null)
    {
        anonymousId = feature.AnonymousId;
    }
    return anonymousId;
}
```

Test Result:

[image]

Is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks, should I add it to app.UseAnonymousId(); to program.,cs or Startup.cs?

Comment: Hi @Shiloh, yes, it should be added in your ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project.

Comment: Chen, thank you that was exactly what I needed, and I've gotten everything working, thanks again!